# TortoiseSVN write-lock error?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Wanted to merge my branch back into the main trunk today. Haven't worked on this project for a week and haven't done any commits, etc. in that time-frame. Attempted to do a switch from the branch back to the trunk and get this error:

```
No write-lock in 'Y:\Website\_Working Copy\app'
```

I've never had or seen this issue in the past and can't find any documentation on what is going wrong...what could this be and what can I try?

Also, I just upgraded TortoiseSVN & SVN to latest versions to see if that would repair a damaged file but no-go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hmm... That is odd, but it's a problem in your working copy.  I'd abort troubleshooting the svn switch by getting a fresh checkout the trunk.  You should then be able to merge the branch into this new working copy.

Comment: Giving you the point for the logic...I was able to do a good checkout of the trunk but overall I've still got issues...I've determined the main cause of all these errors to be that of Beanstalk so now it's on them to resolve. Thanks!

Comment: I am unable to go around int Ubuntu getting the following error :svn: E155005: No write-lock in "some path"

Answer (score 31):

I was switching from a branch to trunk and just got the same error.

With TortoiseSvn, I was able to do a "Clean Up" and that fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Use a terminal screen to navigate to the root directory of the project if your Tortoise "Clean Up" is not working - mine was locked, so I went in via the terminal and type "svn cleanup" and that did the trick.

Comment: I was having this issue on Eclipse and a "Team > Clean Up" fixed it.

Answer (score 14):

If you're using TortoiseSVN, what could be happening is that a (wayward) TSVNCache process is holding open .svn/wc.db which prevents a write lock on the file from being created during the switch operation. Killing the process (or at least forcing the handle closed) will release the handle on the file, allowing other operations that modify the working copy metadata to happen.

Comment: You'll have to do another SVN update after killing the TSVNCache process. Then it will work. (I also restarted Windows Explorer, just to be sure.)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in a recurrent fashion, always in the same project, at each and every commit.  Chris' answer may work (i.e. restart TSVNCache process) but that's a one off.

What cleared off the problem **definitively** for me was to:

- 1) go down to the file(s) that TSVN complained about, and do *SVN Update* on each of them, TSVN then issues a "merged file ..." message, because of the commit that succeeded, but the automated update that had failed.
- 2) once all files were committed and my overall project directory stable, 
  I deleted the to folder, and checked it out from scratch.

No more problems since. Touch wood.

Answer (score 0):

> I was switching from a branch to trunk and just got the same error.

> With TortoiseSvn, I was able to do a "Clean Up" and that fixed the issue for me.

Just addition in Mike's answer while clean up, you have to select "Break if locks" option.