# SVN Delete resulting in an Subversion error being reported

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I wanted to `SVN Delete` but i get the following error

```
Subversion reported an error
No write-lock in "c:\Project Folder"
```

I tried rechecking from the trunk but I still get the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [TortoiseSVN write-lock error?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9403185/tortoisesvn-write-lock-error)

Comment: yes but that did not help me

Answer (score 1):

Seems the van working copy is in inconsistent state. Try **cleanup** and then try to **delete**